# Looking at href values of children

Tags: jquery

How do I look at the child values of an href within a parent ID and check to see if it matches the current URL?  Then, apply a class to the parent and a class to the matching child element.

```
<!-- notice the ID on the li - "aboutsection" -->
<ul id="mainnav" class="nav navbar-nav">

 <!-- About -->


            <li class="dropdown jsb-fw" id="aboutsection"><a href="#" 

data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="100" data-close-others="false" 

class="dropdown-toggle">About</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                 <li class="grid-output">

                   <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-3 about">

                    <h3 class="menuHeading">About US</h3>   
                    <ul>    
                       <li><a 

href="http://localhost:8500/mysite/pagetestcurrent.cfm">Link to this page </a></li>
                       <li><a 

href="http://localhost:8500/mysite/anotherpage.cfm"> Link to another page </a></li>

                   </ul>
            </div>
           </div>
             </li>
           </ul>
        </li>   

  </ul>

<!-- if we are on any of the pages in the dropdown menu (which would 

be either'pagetestcurrent' or 'anotherpage' as in the example above as 

children of the about section), put a currentTab class on the above li 

with the ID 'aboutsection'-->
```

jQuery that adds the class to the id 'aboutsection'.  Currently adds the class regardless of the href values in the children.

```
<script>
$('#aboutsection a').filter(function(){
    return this.href = window.location.href;
}).parent().addClass('currentTab');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return this.href == window.location.href;
}).parent().addClass('currentTab');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yUrNV/1/) (note that, in JS Fiddle, the URL of the pate isn't the same as the URL of the frame in which the content/result is loaded).

The filter compares the `href` property (which the browser returns as an absolute URL, as opposed to the `.attr('href')` method, which returns whatever string is inside of the attribute, whether relative, absolute or simply a fragment/`id`) and compares that to the current `window.location` of the page.

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: Bless you!  This seems to work.  Maybe my hair pulling is over on this one!  Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  As I have been working on it, I have discovered that it isn't working as expected.  What I'd like for it to do, is apply the class when the value of the href (current URL) is in one of the child links within the ID.  Is this possible?  Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried amending the selector, to: `$('#mysection a')`? And what does "isn't working as expected" mean? What is it doing? What it is it *not* doing?

Comment: Thanks David,  What it is doing is adding the class to the mysection ID regardless of whether or not the current URL is a value of an href in the child.  I have tried the following but no luck.  Note now I am referring to the "aboutsection": $('#aboutsection a').filter(function(){ 
var currentURL = window.location.href; 
if($(this).children('a').attr('href',currentURL)) {
   $('li#aboutsection').addClass('currentTab');
  
)};

Comment: Is this available on the internet, anywhere? Because I can't see how that could be happening. And if the code you're using is the code in your comment (and *not* the code in my answer), I'm confused by your asking me about it.

Comment: No David it is not on the web, and no the code I posted is just another attempt to get it to work.  That's Okay, I'll figure it out eventually.  Thanks anyway..

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML you're using, so I can try and replicate your problem (and post a solution that addresses that problem)?

Comment: Can I paste the HTML in here?  I'm new to posting here.

Comment: Of course, click the `edit` link (below the tags to your question), paste the HTML, and jQuery, into your question (only the minimal necessary code to reproduce your problem) and then select that pasted content and click the `{ }` button to automatically format it as code.

Comment: See the updated answer; for some reason I used assignation (`=`), instead of comparison (`==`), operators. Why yes, I *can* be an idiot... :( (It *should* work, now...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`$('#mysection a').filter(function (){ return this.href==window.location.href}).closest('#mysection').addClass(...)`

OR

`$('#mysection:has(a[href='+window.location.href+'])').addClass(...)`